# Django URL not working with parenthesis

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I have a URL that looks like this in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^ex/(?P<example>[\w ]+)$', views.example, name = 'example')
```

One of my variables looks like this: `/ex/(something)/`. I get a 404 page not found with the the URL and I know that it has to do with the parentheses. How do I fix this without changing the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `(` and `)` to the character class for your `example` group.

```
url(r'^ex/(?P<example>[\w ()]+)$', views.example, name='example'),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url(r'^ex/(?P<example>.*)$', views.example, name = 'example')
```

Comment: `.*` will match every character, I would avoid it where possible.

Answer (score 0):

you must review your view

```
def example(request, example):
    # your logic view
    return render(request, 'example.html', {'example': example})
```

if you use `get_object_or404` and the models don't exist Django return a 404 code

and the url should like this:

```
url(r'^ex/(?P<example>[\w]+)$', views.example, name = 'example')
```

or

```
url(r'^ex/(?P<example>[a-zA-Z]+)$', views.example, name = 'example')
```

in url, Django use the regular expression to make your url. Also, if you use the parentheses, you must escape it